# Proper way to use `class_attribute` with `Hash`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mutable, class-variables

Rails has a class extension called [`class_attribute`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#class-attributes) which allows the inheritance of class instance variables. This works fine with immutable objects, e.g. `String`, but not with mutables:

```ruby
class Base
  class_attribute :options
  self.options = {}
end

class SubClass < Base
end

Base.options                   # {}
SubClass.options[:foo] = "bar" # { foo: "bar" }
Base.options                   # { foo: "bar" }
```

The question is how to let subclasses have their own copy of `options` without explicitly initializing it in their body:

```
class SubClass < Base
  self.options = {}
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to use the `inherited` method in the parent class:

```ruby
class Base
  class_attribute :options
  self.options = {}

  class << self
    def inherited(subClass)
      subClass.options = self.options.clone
    end
  end
end
```

this will automatically clone the parent's options every time it is subclassed.

Comment: Great tip that saved me a lot of time - but the given code example won't work like this due to a couple of typos / incorrectly named vars / wrong receiver etc. in the `inherited` hook: Instead of `self._options = self._options.clone` it should be `subClass.options = self.options.clone` ...

Comment: This answer also helped me, but you need to include `super` at the end of your `inherited` method or you'll end up with errors (`undefined method 'synchronize' for nil:NilClass` in my case). Please update the answer if you can.